# How do I perform a simple string mapping as part of a t-sql select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In T-SQL, I can do arithmetic as part of a select. For example, suppose I have a table Math with a column named Decimal. I can do the following query.

```
SELECT 100*Decimal FROM Math
```

I wonder if it's also possible to do logic in the SELECT where I create a mapping such as {
A=>B, F=>Z} so that every time the column is A, it returns B, and every time the column is F, it returns Z.

I apologize if this is a newb question, because I'm not very experienced in SQL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want to use the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) expression:

```
SELECT 
  CASE column1 
    when 'A' THEN 'B' 
    when 'F' THEN 'Z' 
  END 
FROM Tbl
```

Also note that there are two different syntaxes for it, choose one that is most appropriate for you.

Comment: All three answers were helpful, but this solved my implicit problem the best, and I appreciate the link to documentation. 
I didn't know about the existence of the CASE statement in SQL until I saw this.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a table variable that has two columns, one for what is being mapped and another for what it is being mapped to.  Then just join to that table variable on the column you want to remap.

The CASE statements work great for a small number of comparisons, but if you want to do many remappings then the table variable might be the better option.

something like this...

```
DECLARE @Mappings TABLE
(
  MapFrom VARCHAR(50),
  MapTo VARCHAR(50)
)

insert into @Mappings values 
('A', 'B'), 
('F', 'Z'), 
('other', 'mappings');


select m.MapTo
from yourTable t
inner join @Mappings m on m.MapFrom = t.columnName
```

Comment: Another bonus of the table variable approach is that if you need to map multiple columns, or map multiple times on different queries in a stored procedure, it remains clean without duplicating the case statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN YourColumn = 'A' THEN 'B'
            WHEN YourColumn = 'F' THEN 'Z'
            ELSE YourColumn
       END AS MappedColumn
    FROM YourTable
```