# Rename the data (not the columns) that the query (sql) brings without affecting the database (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

The question is the following, I need to rename the data when it is brought in the query without affecting the database, for example, when the name of a column is changed using AS and this does not affect the database, what I want doing is purely visual,

A User table containing: Name Last name

The `Name` column has the following values for example:

| Name |
| --- |
| Estyp |
| Carlos |
| Erik |
| Jean |

What I am looking for is that after making the query instead of returning those names, it returns the results below:

| Name | (Explanation) |
| --- | --- |
| Lucy | i.e. Estyp changed to Lucy |
| Edward | ... Carlos changed to Eduard |
| Aldanis | ... Erik changed to Aldanis |
| Dilam | ... Jean changed to Dilam |

All of the above is visual, it doesn't have to alter the database.

Comment: I think I understood what you mean when say _"rename the columns AS"_ but what do you mean when you say _"Rename the data"_?

Comment: An SQL "Select col1+col2 From myTable;" for example would not leave any persistent calculation results in the DB

Comment: I just edited the post, that's what I mean.

Comment: As far as I understand you, the solution of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096969/how-do-i-perform-a-simple-string-mapping-as-part-of-a-t-sql-select) could help you.

Comment: Do you have an SQL pseudo code example perhaps? Something like this `Case When` example would not alter the DB: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6088ebdde60761a66b1f75fdc632fdec

Comment: It does not work for me, it is showing differently, they are the names of the columns, not the data

Comment: You can address StackOverflow members using the @ character like @C0rn for example

Comment: I already noticed, if it works, I hadn't put the single quotes, thank you very much.

Comment: @jarlh, interesting!, what caused the IBM `db2` Tag addition?, if there were hints, I had not seen them

Comment: @StefanWuebbe, the title says DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this `Select Case When` example line would not *"alter the DB"*:

```
Create Table test (col1 Char(50));
Insert Into Test Values ('Jean ');
Select Case When col1 = 'Jean' Then 'Dilam' End From test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6088ebdde60761a66b1f75fdc632fdec